# page can not be reach when add [Authorize] in using JWT

Tags: c#, api, jwt

After more than one week I try to use JWT in my API,
When I send jwt token from postman or want to get data as json and add Authorize attribute on my controller I got  error 404

these are my codes:

this is my slat generator in separate class:

```
 public static  string  GenerateJsonWebToken()
    {
        var  securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(CreateSlatConstant.Secret));
        var credetials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        var claims = new[] {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub,"123"),
            new Claim("Admin","true"),
          
        };

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            CreateSlatConstant.Issuer,
            CreateSlatConstant.Audiance,
            claims,
            notBefore:DateTime.Now,
            expires:DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120),
            signingCredentials:credetials);

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }
```

and this is JWTcontroller to call slat by this address https://localhost:44305/api/Jwt

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class JWTController : ControllerBase
{


    public IActionResult JwtToken()
    {
        var tt =  MI.Core.CreateSalt.GenerateJsonWebToken();
        return Ok(tt);
    }
}
```

And this is my startup.cs in my Api project

```
   services.AddAuthentication("OAuth")
.AddJwtBearer("OAuth", option =>
{
   option.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
   {
      ValidIssuer = CreateSlatConstant.Issuer,
      ValidAudience = CreateSlatConstant.Audiance,
      IssuerSigningKey = new 
SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(CreateSlatConstant.Secret))
   };
   });
```

and this is My control that call from postman with Token

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class CompanyNameController : ControllerBase
{
    private ICompanyNameRepository _companyNameRepository;
    private IMapper _mapper;

    public CompanyNameController(ICompanyNameRepository companyNameRepository, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _companyNameRepository = companyNameRepository;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCarCompanyAsync()
    {
        var cmObj = await _companyNameRepository.GetAllAsync();
        var cvvm = new List<CompanyNameVM>();

        foreach (var obj in cmObj)
        {
            cvvm.Add(_mapper.Map<CompanyNameVM>(obj));
        }
        return Ok(cvvm);
    }
```

In post man send a get request with token that I get from https://localhost:44305/api/Jwt

the same as this
[image]

on this situation I got error that **This site can’t be reached**
if I remove   [Authorize] attribute it work fine, what's my mistake?

Comment: try adding services.AddAuthorization() under services.AddAuthenticatio() in startup

Comment: I have added it befor.